# Is it possible to gain VPN access through RDP

Tags: vpn, tunnel, windows

Scenario:

I have been tasked to resolve an issue for a client's EmailReceiver program. I have the source code on my PC. I have been given RDP Access to a entry point machine, through which I can connect to any other PC as needed.

[image]

I want to run the source code with their settings to simulate what is happening on their Email Receiver program. The problem I have is that since I am technically not on the network, I can't see their inhouse Email Server. For me to properly test the program I need to be on their VPN. Is there a way for me to use the pre-existing RDP connection to grant me access to their VPN.

After doing some research I did find this [Tunneling a TCP/IP connection through RDP](https://superuser.com/questions/130552/tunneling-a-tcp-ip-connection-through-remote-desktop-connection). But this requires a linux machine. I am looking for a windows-to-windows specific solution to this.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.